# How to create a jpg image from the first frame of a video

Tags: php, imagick

I want to create a `jpg` image from the first frame of a video

```
if (extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    $imagick = new Imagick();
    echo 'ok'; // result - 'ok'
}
```

so extension is available
using `phpinfo()` I see that `mp4` extension is supported
folder `imagick` has `0644` permissions

```
$path = 'imagick/test.mp4';
$imagick = new Imagick($path); // error line
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages()[0];
$imagick->writeImage('imagick/test.jpg');
$imagick->destroy();
```

`error`

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open image 'imagick/test.mp4': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3573 in...

Comment: Looks like php doesn't have permission to read or write to the folder. So grant it, or use a different location

Comment: @ADyson - it is `0644`. If it is not correct what permissions should I set ? I tried `0755` - without success

Comment: That should be enough. Are you 100% certain those are the settings on that particular file?

Comment: Please double-check your permissions. _"folder imagick has 0644 permissions"_ -- *folders* should have the executable flag to be accessible (0755). *Files* should not have the executable flag, unless it's actually a program you want to execute. So the folder "imagick" should have permission 0755, the file "imagick/test.mp4" should have 0644. Can you confirm if that is the case?

Comment: Just a comment but is it not easier to just upload the image?

Comment: `imagick` can convert mp4 to jpg? I've only seen `ffmpeg` used for this previously.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - I tried 0755 / 0644 - the error is now like this - `Failed to read the file...` on the same line

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth - upload is not problem. Problem is - how to create the image without using a video editing software

Comment: You need to set delegate properly

Comment: @KenLee - What's that ?